# Use Powershell to delete file from a folder set by windows registry value

Tags: powershell, registry

Sorry if this has been answered before, I have tirelessly searched and cannot find the exact answer I am a Mac user and have not ventured into Windows registry before.

I am creating an installer for audio plugins and have a separate demo version of the titles.  In the registry for the demo version, I have the entry

```
Demo=1
```

and also have paths set for various components of the plugins, which are optionally installed, these are stored in the registry as the user may install these into different directories depending on their host software

```
VST3=C:\Somepath\VST3
VST32=C\AnotherPath\VSTPlugins
VST64=C\AnotherPathAgain\VSTPlugins
```

I have found how to search the registry to check if Demo=1

```
$val = Get-ItemProperty -Path hklm:software\Audio Vitamins\Structure -Name “Demo”
if($val.Demo -eq 1)
{
  **** This is where I need help *****
}
```

How do I set Powershell to remove a particular file 'structure.vst3' from the path set in VST3 or or 'structure.dll' from the paths set in VST32 and VST64. Note these can all be present or only 1 of them depending on the original install.

Comment: Please clarify (directly in your question) what removing a particular file means. Removing a value such as `VST3` as a whole? How do you decide what to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of different paths (pun intended) you can take here. 
You can organize your "demo = 1" files into one folder and the others in another and reference the demo folder location in the registry. Then you get the file location and use **del** to remove them. Much easier and doesn't require you to track which ones are there with unnecessary registry entries.

```
$demofolder = gp -path HKLM:\path\to\registry\key -Name "demofolder"
dir $demofolder -file|%{del $_ -force}
```

Comment: Ok that is an idea, although it does not look very pretty for the user, filling a directory with such folders, but it seems the easiest solution... Thanks